# Selecting ARIMA based on ACF and PACF

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I am facing this set of ACF and PACF graphs, of a log differentiated feature, which is proved stationary through unit root tests. However, I'm having trouble selecting the right ARIMA model: ARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q). Any recommendations on a good fit and why?

Original Graph
[image: Original Graph]

ACF Plot Original Data
[image: ACF Plot Original Data]

PACF Plot Original Data
[image: PACF Plot Original Data]

Log diff Data
[image: Log diff Data]

ACF plot of difference(log(data))
[image: ACF plot of difference(log(data))]

PACF plot of difference(log(data))
[image: PACF plot of difference(log(data))]

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the graphs now.

Comment: How does undifferenced data look?

Comment: Please find the updated graphs above

Comment: It is highly doubtful that you need to difference your data; the original plot and the original ACF, PACF plots do not suggest presence of a unit root. (Overdifferencing seems to be a common mistake.)

Comment: Okay, appreciate the answer. Any suggestions for the ARIMA model based on the ACF and PACF plot, and if so, why?

Comment: *Perhaps* seasonal differencing could be in order. I wonder what seasonal unit root tests would say.

Comment: I think a sounder approach to model selection would be something like the `auto.arima` algorithm rather than eyeballing ACF and PACF. The latter help in the simplest cases such as pure AR(p) or MA(q) but are of limited use in more general cases such as full blown AR(I)MA or SAR(I)MA.

Comment: Appreciate the help Richard, will go on and have a look at seasonal differencing. The reason for eyeballing is that I've learned to always verify the auto.arima function with a selected model based on ACF and PACF, since auto.arima does not necessarily find the global minimum

Comment: Sure, there is no need to blindly trust any algorithm.